Xcode won't install iOS 18.2 SDK
I'm running MacOS Sequoia 15.1.1 and Xcode 16.2 and trying to install the SDK version 18.2. When I click the "Get" button it indicates it is installing / registering the SDK for several seconds then goes back to showing the "Get" button. There are no errors that I can see and don't know where to look for logs on the install (if there are any). Because 18.2 is not installed, trying to compile my .NET MAUI app generates an error indicating there is no simulator runtime version found. According to another post, this error is because the version of the iOS SDK and associated simulator are not installed.
Is there a way to tell why the SDK is not being installed correctly in Xcode? How do I get it to install correctly?

Do you have enough free disk space on your Mac? Did you try restarting Xcode or even your Mac?

I have 615 GB of drive space available and have rebooted twice and restarted Xcode. Same result each time,

I found an error message: (-67061 invalid signature (code or signature have been modified)
Domain: SimDiskImageErrorDomain
Code: 5
User Info: {
DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-12-27 14:57:31 +0000";
unusableErrorDetail = "";
}
(-67061 invalid signature (code or signature have been modified)
Apparently there was an issue with the download, but I don't know where it is stored to remove it and try to download a new version. It is not in the Downloads folder.
